# make Shader Graph material flow aligned to the mesh UVs (like a river)

Tags: unity, unity-shader-graph

i need to add a flow effect to my river so that the water can flow along the path described by the mesh i created. Using ShaderGraph shader i added a `time node` multiplied with a `screen position` and hooked into a `Tiling and Offset node` but the water keep moving in a global direction only.

Please note that i'm using `Instant River` tool to create the river mesh
https://unitylist.com/p/loq/Instant-River

I noticed in its script he's using some methods to rotate and align the UVs, so it should work with any material, but i don't know how to align my shader.

I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve the result with Shader Graph or not. Any idea?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem myself using a `Normal Unpack` node  before the Tiling and Offset one. This gives an orientation along the UVs. I post the solution here for anyone facing the same issue.

[image]

Comment: You should really delete the screen position and normal unpack nodes and just use a UV node instead if you want UVs.

Comment: i tried but it's not working. the UVs don't follow the mesh orientation